# How to Output Downloadable file after processing?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, huggingface, gradio

### Specification

- `gr.__version__  --> '3.16.2'`
- I want to create a gradio tab in mygradio app
- Disregard TAB 1, I am only working on tab2
- where I upload an excel file
- save name of the excel fie to a variable
- process that excel file take data out of it 2 numbers (1 and 2)
- Load data from the excel file to a pandas dataframe and add 1 to both of the numbers
- Turn dataframe to excel again and output it to the user to be able to download the output excel file
- The output file is named as the original uploaded file

### MY CURRENT Code

```
import gradio as gr
import pandas as pd


# def func1():
#     #....
#     pass

def func2(name, file):
    file_name = name
    file_x = file
    # use this function to retrieve the file_x without modification for gradio.io output
    # excel to dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(file_x)
    # add 1 to both numbers
    df['1'] = df['1'] + 1
    df['2'] = df['2'] + 1
    # dataframe to excel
    # returnt the exported excel fiel with the same name as the original file
    return df.to_excel(file_x, index=False)


# GRADIO APP
with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    gr.Markdown("BI App")


    ''' #1.TAB '''
    # with gr.Tab("Tab1"):
    #      #.... unimportant code
    #     with gr.Column():
    #         file_obj = gr.File(label="Input File", 
    #             file_count="single", 
    #             file_types=["", ".", ".csv",".xls",".xlsx"]),
    #         # extract the filename from gradio.io file object
    #         # keyfile_name = gr.Interface(file_name_reader, inputs="file", outputs=None)
    #         keyfile_name = 'nothing'
    #         tab1_inputs = [keyfile_name, file_obj]

    #     with gr.Column():
    #         # output excel file with gradio.io
    #         tab1_outputs = [gr.File(label="Output File", 
    #             file_count="single", 
    #             file_types=["", ".", ".csv",".xls",".xlsx"])]
        
    #     tab1_submit_button = gr.Button("Submit")


    ''' #2.TAB - I EDIT THIS TAB'''
    with gr.Tab("Tab2"):
        admitad_invoice_approvals_button = gr.Button("Submit")

        def file_name_reader(file):
            file_name = file.name  # extract the file name from the uploaded file
            return file_name
        
        # iface = gr.Interface(file_name_reader, inputs="file", outputs=None)

        with gr.Column():
            file_obj = gr.File(label="Input File", 
                file_count="single", 
                file_types=["", ".", ".csv",".xls",".xlsx"]),
            # extract the filename from gradio.io file object
            keyfile_name = gr.Interface(file_name_reader, inputs="file", outputs=None)
            tab2_inputs = [keyfile_name, file_obj]

        with gr.Column():
            # output excel file with gradio.io
            tab2_outputs = [gr.File(label="Output File", 
                file_count="single", 
                file_types=["", ".", ".csv",".xls",".xlsx"])]

        tab2_submit_button = gr.Button("Submit")


    '''1 button for each of the tabs to execute the GUI TASK'''
    # tab1_submit_button.click(func1,
    #                         inputs=tab1_inputs,
    #                         outputs=tab1_outputs)
    
    tab2_submit_button.click(func2,
                            inputs=tab2_inputs,
                            outputs=tab2_outputs)
    

''' EXECUTING THE APP'''
demo.launch(debug=True, share=True) ## PRODUCTION TESTING
```

### ERROR:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 95
     90     '''1 button for each of the tabs to execute the GUI TASK'''
     91     # tab1_submit_button.click(func1,
     92     #                         inputs=tab1_inputs,
     93     #                         outputs=tab1_outputs)
---> 95     tab2_submit_button.click(func2,
     96                             inputs=tab2_inputs,
     97                             outputs=tab2_outputs)
    100 ''' EXECUTING THE APP'''
    101 demo.launch(debug=True, share=True) ## PRODUCTION TESTING

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gradio/events.py:145, in Clickable.click(self, fn, inputs, outputs, api_name, status_tracker, scroll_to_output, show_progress, queue, batch, max_batch_size, preprocess, postprocess, cancels, every, _js)
    140 if status_tracker:
    141     warnings.warn(
    142         "The 'status_tracker' parameter has been deprecated and has no effect."
    143     )
--> 145 dep = self.set_event_trigger(
    146     "click",
    147     fn,
    148     inputs,
    149     outputs,
    150     preprocess=preprocess,
    151     postprocess=postprocess,
    152     scroll_to_output=scroll_to_output,
    153     show_progress=show_progress,
    154     api_name=api_name,
    155     js=_js,
    156     queue=queue,
    157     batch=batch,
    158     max_batch_size=max_batch_size,
    159     every=every,
    160 )
    161 set_cancel_events(self, "click", cancels)
    162 return dep

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gradio/blocks.py:225, in Block.set_event_trigger(self, event_name, fn, inputs, outputs, preprocess, postprocess, scroll_to_output, show_progress, api_name, js, no_target, queue, batch, max_batch_size, cancels, every)
    217         warnings.warn(
    218             "api_name {} already exists, using {}".format(api_name, api_name_)
    219         )
    220         api_name = api_name_
    222 dependency = {
    223     "targets": [self._id] if not no_target else [],
    224     "trigger": event_name,
...
    237 }
    238 Context.root_block.dependencies.append(dependency)
    239 return dependency

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_id'
```

### Tried

- I have looked in to https://gradio.app/docs/#file but the output file generation is not clean especially regarding applying it to my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
        with gr.Column():
            file_obj = gr.File(label="Input File"
# no any other arguments
)
            input= file_obj
```

Just have

```
        with gr.Column():
            file_obj = gr.File(label="Input File")
            input= file_obj
```